# Unable to launch on iPhone 12 Pro

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I was debugging the app normally but today I wanted to test it then this happened.

Terminal Error:

```
Exception: Unable to launch com.example.tubitakbiyo on 7700*******-9633-1DBF73524FA6:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
com.example.tubitakbiyo: -1

An error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=3):
The request to open "com.example.tubitakbiyo" failed.
The process did launch, but has since exited or crashed.
  Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl launch 77F612A*********-633-1DBF73524FA6 com.example.tubitakbiyo --enable-dart-profiling --enable-checked-mode --verify-entry-points --start-paused --observatory-port=0
Error launching application on iPhone 12 Pro.
Exited (sigterm)
```

Problem Report from MAC:

```
Reason: tried: '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot/usr/lib/swift/MTBBarcodeScanner.framework/MTBBarcodeScanner' (no such file), '/usr/lib/swift/MTBBarcodeScanner.framework/MTBBarcodeScanner' (no such file), '/Users/cidqu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/77F612AC-5F9C-4E78-9633-1DBF73524FA6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3A022D9-62FF-40B5-994C-B07D54C684E7/Runner.app/Frameworks/MTBBarcodeScanner.framework/MTBBarcodeScanner' (no such file), '/Users/cidqu/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/77F612AC-5F9C-4E78-9633-1DBF73524FA6/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/F3A022D9-62FF-40B5-994C-B07D54C684E7
dyld4 config: DYLD_ROOT_PATH=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Profiles/Runtimes/iOS.simruntime/Contents/Resources/RuntimeRoot
```

I don't have any other errors. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by unchecking this option, `Run Script: [ ] For install builds only`

[image: You need to Uncheck this option.]